# Show that a certain point lies outside a ball, might be simple but i am stuck...

Tags: geometry, analysis, arithmetic

Consider the ball
$$
  B(0, R) := \{ x | ||x|| \le R \}
$$
and consider a point $x$ outside of the ball, that is $||x|| > R$. Now i construct another ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}(||x|| - R)$ around $x$ and i want to show that these two balls have no points in common. For this consider a $x'$ which lies in the second ball, then the following hold:

- $|x' - x| \le \frac{1}{2}(||x|| - R)$
- $||x|| > R$
- $||x' - x|| + ||x|| \ge ||x'||$ (triangle inequality)

from this i want to deduce that $||x'|| > R$ but i am stuck. Any help?

Comment: It would help to give a different name to the center of the second ball, maybe $c$.  You use $x$ in more than one context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}$Use the 'other' triangle inequality, your version gives upper bounds for $\norm{x'}$ which aren't of any help to deduce lower bounds. We have (by the triangle inequality $\norm{x} \le \norm{x'} + \norm{x-x'}$ and your other two inequalities)
\begin{align*}
  \norm{x'} &\ge \norm{x} - \norm{x-x'}\\
            &\ge \norm{x} - \frac 12(\norm x - R)\\
            &= \frac 12\norm x + \frac 12R\\
            &> \frac 12 R + \frac 12R\\
            &= R.
\end{align*}